# Error al crear Servicio Windows con C#

Tags: c#, windows, servicio

soy nuevo en el uso de visual estudio, estoy tratando de crear un servicio windows a partir de este tutorial [tutorial crear servicio windows](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/create-and-install-windows-service-step-by-step-in-C-Sharp/) pero en TestService.cs me sale el error **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto**, abajo les dejo el código

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class TestService : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timeDelay;
        int count;
        public TestService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timeDelay = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timeDelay.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(WorkProcess);
        }
        public void WorkProcess(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string process = "Timer Tick " + count;
            LogService(process);
            count++;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            LogService("Service is Started");
            timeDelay.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            LogService("Service Stoped");
            timeDelay.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void LogService(string content)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\TestServiceLog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine(content);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

desde ya gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: A groso modo no se ve nada raro.. igual el ejemplo esta tal cual como esta en csharp corner, seria bueno que colocara la traza del error que le esta generando

Comment: ¿En qué línea te sale ese error?